# Route protection Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am building an app that has a client list for multiple users. Each user should have access to only their client list. (a next step is to add the ability for users to allow other users access to their client list).

I have the app set up to protect the list using built-in middleware. The URL /clients shows only the authenticated user's list. However, I cannot figure out how to protect the client detail.

I have my user model set up with hasMany on the clients, and client set up with belongsTo on user.

How do I protect a URL such as /clients/5 , where 5 is a client ID in my database, and the URL shows the client detail? Currently, any authenticated user can type the url with the client ID, and view that client detail. I can post code if needed. But, I am just looking to be pointed in the right direction to figure it out myself.

Edit - additional info / code

Here is the show function from ClientsController.php The commented out bit is a failed attempt at solving the question posted here.

```
  public function show($id)
{
    //$client = \Auth::user()->clients()->get($id);
    $client = Client::findOrFail($id);
    return view('clients.show', compact('client'));
}
```

And, my Client model

```
 namespace App;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class Client extends Model
 {
   protected $fillable = [
    'bizName',
    'bizStreet',
    'bizCity',
    'bizZip',
    'bizEmail',
    'bizPhone',
    'bizNotes',
    'user_id'
];

/**
 * A client belongs to one user
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

}

Comment: Would you please update your question with the content of your `ClientController@show` or the controller for `/clients/{clients}` route? Maybe even insert your `Clients` model as well.

Answer (score 1):

For starters you can use something like this in your middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(($request->id != $request->user()->id) and ($request->user()->is_admin != true))
    {
        exit('Nice try!');
    } 

    return $next($request);
}
```

You may also like the following: https://github.com/jenssegers/optimus

Comment: I am not sure how to pass the logged-in user id from the requesting view. Can you direct me on that bit?

Comment: `$request->user()` is your logged-in user, `$request->id` is your route parameter, such as `{id}`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who offered help.

I could not get middleware to work. So, I changed the show method in my controller to use an if statement as a filter.

Here is my working show method:

```
 public function show($id)
  {
    $client = Client::findOrFail($id);
    if ($client->user_id != \Auth::id())
    {
        return view('welcome');
        //TODO create unauthorized view
    }
    return view('clients.show', compact('client'));
  }
```